# I don't understand what is the verb "do" doing in this sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> "Only in Queensland **do** people brag about the weather as if they built it themselves."

https://twitter.com/Bris_Powerhouse/status/705285083020656641

Wouldn't it sound better or make more sense by simply omitting it?

> "Only in Queensland people brag about the weather as if they built it themselves."

Or is it doing something like:

> "Only in Queensland **is where** people brag about the weather as if they built it themselves."

Can someone, please, explain? Is it adding some sort of different emphasis?

Comment: "To do" is also used as an auxiliary for emphasis.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I don't see how this question could be related to the one you're suggesting. It's not about word positioning. It actually more about if the word (**do**) should even be there. And, if so, why?

Comment: @jpablobr *Do* has to be there. Read Araucaria's answer carefully, and you would see why ("why" for learners, not "why" for linguists, by the way). -- To give a few more hints, consider: *I like it*. You can emphasize your feeling by saying *I do like it*; whereas *I like do it* is ungrammatical, and we wouldn't use *Do I like it* as a declarative sentence. In the same way, *Only in Queensland people brag about the weather ...* or *Only in Queensland people do brag about the weather ...* is ungrammatical, and we must use *Only in Queensland do people brag about the weather ...*

Comment: @DamkerngT. Wow, you were right! Thank you! And yes, this is then a duplicate question...

Comment: @jpablobr No problem! The more important thing is that you can understand the usage. I'm glad that that question can help!